# How to create multi-file template in PhpStorm (or WebStorm)?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, phpstorm, webstorm

I need 2 files for creating new component in React:

**${NAME}.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import css from './${NAME}.css';
const ${NAME} = () => (
  <div></div>
);
export default ${NAME};
```

**${NAME}.css**

```
/* Empty */
```

*Note: **${NAME}** needs to be entered like constant while creating these files.*

I would like to use PhpStorm (or WebStorm) **file template feature** (or some other simple way) to **create both files** - by only clicking to create component like on image below:

[image: Example]

Is something like that possible ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I'm aware it's not possible right now unless you code a plugin for that yourself.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91565 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

**UPDATE 2020-12-04:** The aforementioned ticket has been fixed and multi-file templates are available since **2020.3 version**.

---

Some links if you are thinking about coding it yourself:

- [IntelliJ Platform SDK / Plugin Development Docs](https://jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/)
- [API Forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development)
- [Some example](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206775565-How-to-work-with-templates)

Comment: Thanks - seems like we need to wait till such functionality is implemented in IDE core.

Comment: Are there any Plugins that actually do this though? That would be awesome. I'm thinking of just making something, rather than using my wonderful bash scripts..